# Navbar Elements always under Collapsible Navbar Button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a navbar that has a few items within it and when the dimensions of the window are shrunk, I have a collapsible button holding those items. The issue is that no matter how large my window is, the navbar items are remaining in the button rather than being expanded across the navbar as intended. I've attached a pic of what is happening. Below you can find the HTML. Any advice on why the navbar items are under this collapsible button all the time? Thanks! Also, can't seem to figure out why the navbar brand image, although left-aligned, isn't close to the very left of the window.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" /></title>

<c:set var="contextRoot" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="${contextRoot}/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="${contextRoot}/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script     src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">.      </script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Static navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
    <!--    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed"
            data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
            aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> <span
                class="icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar">.   </span> <span
                class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button> -->
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Spring Boot Tutorial</a> -->
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="${contextRoot}/img/bcore-bride+AI.png" width=8% height=8%/></a>

    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="${contextRoot}/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="${contextRoot}/newRecord">New Record</a></li>

        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="${contextRoot}/account">Account</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>

<div><tiles:insertAttribute name="content" /></div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="${contextRoot}/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: navbar button with items that should be expanded across navbar]

Comment: add your full html code along with which bootstrap version using.

Comment: Done. And the Bootstrap v is 4.5.0.

Comment: link which you refer for bootstrap ?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com

Comment: your code and class is not matching have you done customisation ?

Comment: Oh yes I have. What do I need instead to align with 4.5.0? Link?

Comment: Follow website guideline. it should work if not then you ask here.